# Canvas Limits with javascript

Tags: limits, canvas

I am looking for more information about canvas limits. I found documentation where they said 5000 calls per user per 24 hours (This includes SDK calls to get context and signed request calls. Note that when you call a SignedRequest method, there are actually two calls that are made—one call for the method and one call for internal logging.) - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_framework_limits.htm
But what about javascripts? Is it included there call javascript functions publish, subscribe,... ?
What if I call javascript function publish from 3th party app into visualforce, where I have actionfunction. Is it callculated into some limits.

Is there some way how I can check used limits in canvas? I tried to look in company information, but there is only API request, and it seams that if i work with canvas, this API request are on the same numbers.

Thank you